# SQLParse - issue with the wildcard LIKE condition

Tags: python, sql-like, identifier, sql-parser

I'm focusing on the Where clause of a SQL statement and I'm trying to pull back all the columns used in the Where clause. Below is an example SQL:

```
sql_2 = """Select
PERS_ID
, STF_NO
, NAME 
FROM 
TEST T

WHERE T.JOIN_DT >= T.POSTING_DT'
AND T.PERS_ID LIKE '%123%'
AND T.LEAVE_DT BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - 20 AND CURRENT_DATE - 1"""
```

The columns I am expecting are T.JOIN_DT, T.POSTING_DT, T.PERS_ID and T.LEAVE_DT. The code below is able to pull out all but T.PERS_ID

```
from __future__ import print_function
import re
import sqlparse 
import numpy as np
from sqlparse.sql import IdentifierList, Identifier, Function, Where, Parenthesis, TokenList, Comparison, Operation
from sqlparse.tokens import Keyword, DML, Punctuation

sql_2 = """Select
    PERS_ID
    , STF_NO
    , NAME 
    FROM 
    TEST T
    
    WHERE T.JOIN_DT >= T.POSTING_DT'
    AND T.PERS_ID LIKE '%123%'
    AND T.LEAVE_DT BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - 20 AND CURRENT_DATE - 1"""

parsed = sqlparse.parse(sql_2)[0]

where_columns = []
full_columns = []

for item in parsed.tokens:
    if isinstance(item, Where):

        
        for condition in item.tokens:
            
            if isinstance(condition, Identifier):
                where_columns.append(condition.get_parent_name())
                where_columns.append(condition.get_real_name())
                full_columns.append(where_columns)
                where_columns = []
        
                       
            if isinstance(condition, Comparison):
                for breakdown in condition.tokens:
                    if isinstance(breakdown, Identifier):
                        where_columns.append(breakdown.get_parent_name())
                        where_columns.append(breakdown.get_real_name())
                        full_columns.append(where_columns)
                        where_columns = []
                              

print(full_columns)
```

It seems to group the 'AND P.PERS_ID LIKE '%123' into one token, and I'm unsure how to break it down further to get the identifier P.PERS_ID. If you add `print(condition)` after `for condition in item.tokens:` you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have a trailing quote after T.POSTING_DT

My library [SQLGlot](https://github.com/tobymao/sqlglot) however is able to easily extract out the columns.

```
import sqlglot
import sqlglot.expressions as exp

sql = """
Select
PERS_ID
, STF_NO
, NAME
FROM
TEST T

WHERE T.JOIN_DT >= T.POSTING_DT'
AND T.PERS_ID LIKE '%123%'
AND T.LEAVE_DT BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - 20 AND CURRENT_DATE - 1
"""

for column in sqlglot.parse_one(sql).find(exp.Where).find_all(exp.Column):
    print(column.text("this"))


CURRENT_DATE
CURRENT_DATE
LEAVE_DT
PERS_ID
POSTING_DT'
JOIN_DT
```